# Excel macro to remove rows containing variable text

Tags: excel, vba, search, delete-row, excel-2016

This is my first time posting.

I'm trying to find a way in Excel 2016 to clean up a folder list so that I only have the parent folders.

I have a spreadsheet where column A is a list of folders, including their subfolders. Like this: [fyi - there are other columns in each row, but they are not relevant to this example]

```
\\server\share\root\subfolder1\
\\server\share\root\subfolder1\sub-subfolderA\
\\server\share\root\subfolder1\sub-subfolderB\
\\server\share\root\subfolder1\sub-subfolderC\
\\server\share\root\subfolder2\
\\server\share\root\subfolder2\other-subfolderA\
\\server\share\root\subfolder2\other-subfolderB\
\\server22\share\root\subfolder3\ham_sandwich\
\\server22\share\root\subfolder3\ham_sandwich\yet-another-subfolderA\
\\server22\share\root\subfolder3\and-another-subfolderA\
\\server22\share\root\subfolder3\and-another-subfolderB\
```

There are approximately 2500 rows with folders of varying length, and my ultimate goal is to end up with only the top level folders of each "set". For example:

```
\\server\share\root\subfolder1\
\\server\share\root\subfolder2\
\\server22\share\root\subfolder3\ham_sandwich\
\\server22\share\root\subfolder3\and-another-subfolderA\
\\server22\share\root\subfolder3\and-another-subfolderB\
```

The logic I have for this is as follows (and please correct me if I am overlooking anything):

```
See if the string in A1 is contained within the string in A2.
  If A2 contains the string, delete row 2.
  If it doesn't, move down to compare A2 with A3. [since we know A1 is now the only cell containing that top folder]
Rinse-and-repeat until the last populated row is reached.
```

My issue is figuring out the code for this. I'm seeing all sorts of code snippets online regarding searching for specified text, but nothing that uses a variable. I was originally toying with the formula combination of IsNumber and Search, but it requires fixed text to search, where this would be changing as the macro progresses.

Can someone point me in the right direction for this?

Comment: 1) How do you determine which folders  are "top level". i.e. why is `\\server\share\root\subfolder1\` in your results. but not `\\server\share\root\`? is it because it't listed at the start of each set?

Comment: By your pseudo-code, you would delete `...\subfolder1\sub-subfolderA`, then compare `..\subfolder1\sub-subfolderB\ ` to `..\subfolder\sub-subfolderC\ `

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad - you have "1)" which implies there would be a "2)" coming, but that doesn't seem to have made the cut...

Comment: I'm thinking there's a relatively quick way to do this, using `Text to Columns` with a delimiter `\`...but can't quite get there.  In the end, are you looking for a list of such folders, or do you actually want to remove those rows that are NOT a sub-folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that the top level folder is *always* listed before the sub folders:

```
k = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = k - 1 To 1 Step -1
    For j = k To i + 1 Step -1
        If InStr(Range("A" & j), Range("A" & i)) > 0 Then
            Rows(j).Delete
            k = k - 1
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: Nice thinking with the `InStr`, quick and clever answer!

Comment: Given that time was not a factor for me, I found this to be the most elegant solution, and matched my initial logic. I had actually also cobbled together something with InStr when I was waiting for replies, but it wasn't nearly as simple, and required multiple re-runs. In fairness, I would have also liked to accepted Ron Rosenfeld's solution, but in my singular case, cybernetic.nomad's smaller code suited my needs better (and without the need to specify ranges). A huge thank you to all contributors!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a long list, it will be faster to process the list using a VBA array, rather than repeated worksheet read/writes.

The macro ASSUMES the data is SORTED as you show.  If not, add a routine to sort it first.

We go through each item, and check to see if the previously stored item can be found.  Based on that, we determine whether to store the results in our dictionary.  Then we output that to the worksheet.

You can see where you can vary the range to process and where you want the results, in the code.

```
'Set reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Option Explicit
Sub cleanList()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim dList As Dictionary
    Dim V, I As Long

Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("sheet1")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 2) 'results in column B

'Assume data starts in A1
'Read into variant array for speed of processing
With wsSrc
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With

'collect results
Set dList = New Dictionary
    dList.CompareMode = TextCompare

For Each V In vSrc
    If dList.Count = 0 Then
        dList.Add Key:=V, Item:=V
    ElseIf InStr(V, dList.Keys(dList.Count - 1)) = 0 Then
            dList.Add Key:=V, Item:=V
    End If
Next V

'create results array
ReDim vRes(1 To dList.Count, 1 To 1)
I = 0
For Each V In dList
    I = I + 1
    vRes(I, 1) = V
Next V

'set results range
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(rowsize:=UBound(vRes, 1))

'write results to worksheet
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

one of the possible solutions (based on your dataset):

```
Sub test()
    Dim dic As Object: Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Range([A1], Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    Dim cl As Range, x As Variant, cntr&: cntr = 0

    dic.Add cntr, rng.Cells(1).Value2: cntr = cntr + 1
    For Each cl In rng
        If Not LCase(cl.Value2) Like LCase(dic(cntr - 1)) & "*" Then
            dic.Add cntr, cl.Value2: cntr = cntr + 1
        End If
    Next cl

    For Each x In dic
        Debug.Print dic(x)
    Next x
End Sub
```

test below:

[image]